# Mac OS X Keychain Certificate "member: VERY_LONG_GUID"

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain

I am seeing untrusted certificate added to keychain, which has naming like "member: LONG_GUID" probably 64 char long GUID. I tried deleting but it's coming back.

I am concerned about it being virus or something else.

Any one knows what is it? Also, is there way to know who added/created certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but... its access control settings do hint at a key for `studentd`, which is vaguely discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/357284/what-is-the-studentd-process) (and `man studentd`, of course). Found it so far on all machines running Mojave (10.14).

Comment: That was it. I have unloaded studentd process and that certificate didn't come back. Thanks!

Comment: @kthorat How dod you "unload" the process? I Force Quit it and it just restarts immediately.

Comment: @Arbitur I disabled System Integrity Protection to unload studentd then enabled SIP again. That worked for me.